# Phone contacts list displayed without contacts from a different google acount which I added on my phone

Tags: google-account, google-contacts

I use my friend's google account on my Android phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 11 Pro) to help him sell on ebay. All his phone numbers from his contacts list now appear in my contacts list. I don't want the numbers from his list to show up, what can I do?  I also want to continue using his account, to help him.

Comment: Why do you need a google account to access ebay?

Comment: It' s something similar with Ebay, called Wallapop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings` -> `Accounts & Users` (dont enter Google) -> `select your friend's Google account` -> `turn off sync`

You will then have to manually delete all his contacts from your Contacts App.

Next time remember to turn off syncs when logging in to Google accounts :)